# Converting null-terminated lines to JSON strings with jq

Tags: json, string, jq, nul

I've come up with a `jq`-based one-liner that converts a sequence of null-terminated strings to a sequence of JSON strings:

```
xargs -0 dash -c 'for i in "$@"; do printf %s "$i" | jq -Rs . ; done' _dummy_
```

I'd like to cut `xargs` and/or `dash` out of it if possible. Is there a way to do the same thing with just `jq`?

Example usage:

```
# Create a new dir with some funny-named files
mkdir funny
cd funny
touch $'ABC\nDEF' $' GHI\nJKL ' ' - はじめまして - '
# Use find -print0 to list the files
find -type f -print0 |
# Convert the null-terminated lines to JSON strings
xargs -0 dash -c 'for i in "$@"; do printf %s "$i" | jq -Rs . ; done' _dummy_
```

Output:

```
"./ - はじめまして - "
"./ GHI\nJKL "
"./ABC\nDEF"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces the output you've specified:

```
find . -type f -print0 | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000")[]'
```

Comment: Given that the input is null-terminated and not null-delimited, I wonder why a split operation doesn't have an extra blank string at the end. Seems to be a special case; compare the output of `printf 'ABCxDEFxGHIx' | jq -Rs 'split("x")[]'` to that of `printf 'ABC\0DEF\0GHI\0' | jq -Rs 'split("\u0000")[]'`. Weird.

Comment: The -R option chomps a terminating `\n` and `\0` except for the special case `\n\0`.

Comment: Is this documented?